# using Qhull without points?

Tags: convex-hulls

I'm trying to use the [Qhull program](http://www.qhull.org/) to solve for convex hull. It seems to only take points as inputs. But my convex hull is so far only defined by the equation, i.e. ${\displaystyle \mathrm {Conv} (S)=\left\{\left.\sum _{i=1}^{|S|}\alpha _{i}x_{i}\ \right|(\forall i:\alpha _{i}\geq 0)\wedge \sum _{i=1}^{|S|}\alpha _{i}=1\right\}.}$

All the $\bf{x_{i}}$ vectors are known.

So can I just use $x_{i}$ as the points? are they the same as the vertices? or should I be randomly sample a bunch of points that fits in this equation, and then feed those points into the qhull program?

Answer (score 1):

The equation you gave is just the characterization of the convex hull of a set of points as the set of convex combinations of the points. So you can just give the points to Qhull.